# Flutter Navigator error

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema com o Navigator do Flutter:

Através de um determinado screen estou a fazer push de uma rota desta forma:

```
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).getAddresses()
                              .then((value) => Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed('/user_locations'));
```

Apenas estou fazendo um request antes que não tem qualquer return e depois sim o push da nova rota.

Dentro desta nova rota, ao clicar num dos botões disponíveis, estou aceder a um novo método do Provider:

```
onTap: ()  {
       Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).setDefaultAddress(addresses[index]['id'], context);
},
```

Aqui estou passando apenas um Id e o context. Este método está definido desta forma:

```
Future<dynamic> setDefaultAddress(int addressId, BuildContext context) async {
    updateLoading(true);
    var url = Uri.parse(API_URL + 'set-default-address');
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
    String json = '{"token": "$token", "address_id": "$addressId"}';

try {
      Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      await updateAddress(data);
      await updateLoading(false);
      Navigator.pop(context);
      return;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      updateLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

tudo é executado sem problemas ou erros excepto quando chega ao Navigator.pop(context) onde surge esse erro:

```
I/flutter (19250): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
I/flutter (19250): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
I/flutter (19250): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Já procurei outros tópicos com este tema mas nenhuma das soluções resolve o meu problema :(

Obrigado